# SET NOCOUNT ON in a vb.net project

Tags: sql, vb.net, nocount

Setting "SET NOCOUNT ON" in a application always benefits the performance of the application. But how i can set it in my vb.net application in a better way. Is it possible to set it in connection string? Is there any best approach to do it? Setting it each time will be problem or there may be chance of missing it out.

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio right click on server node: `Properties -> Connections -> Default connection options`. Tick `no count`.